# concrete implemantation of IEnumerable<T> that is not ICollection<T>

Tags: c#, collections, nunit, ienumerable, test-coverage

I would like to know if any of the classes in the .net framework that implement IEnumerable  doesn't implement the ICollection interface.

I'm asking it because I can't get 100% code coverage in the following extension method that I wrote:

```
public static int GetSafeCount<T>(this IEnumerable<T> nullableCollaction)
    {
        if (nullableCollaction == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        var collection = nullableCollaction as ICollection<T>;
        if (collection != null)
        {
            return collection.Count;
        }
        return nullableCollaction.Count();
    }
```

The last line is not covered in any of my tests and I can't find the correct class to instantiate in order to cover it.

my test code is:

```
[Test]
    public void GetSafeCount_NullObject_Return0()
    {
        IEnumerable<string> enumerable=null;

        Assert.AreEqual(0, enumerable.GetSafeCount());
    }
    [Test]
    public void GetSafeCount_NonICollectionObject_ReturnCount()
    {
        IEnumerable<string> enumerable = new string[]{};

        Assert.AreEqual(0, enumerable.GetSafeCount());
    }
```

Comment: Isn't that what `Enumerable.Count()` already does?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: No, because if the argument to `Enumerable.Count` is null, it will throw an exception.

Comment: @JonSkeet then only the null check is necessary. The rest of the code can be removed. The unit test would only have to check for correct null handling

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Indeed, as I've said in my answer :) (For the first part - adding the last part now.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Stack<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw(v=vs.110).aspx) class, it implements `ICollection` and `IEnumerable<T>` but not `ICollection<T>`.

Here is how the class is defined:

```
public class Stack<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable, ICollection, 
    IReadOnlyCollection<T>
```

Comment: but it's also not an IEnumerable<T>

Comment: @silver, it is `IEnumerable<T>`. You can check the MSDN documentation link I provided.

Answer (score 2):

Just use any LINQ operation, e.g. `Where`:

```
[Test]
public void GetSafeCount_NonICollectionObject_ReturnCount()
{
    IEnumerable<string> enumerable = new string[0].Where(x => x.Length == 0);
    Assert.AreEqual(0, enumerable.GetSafeCount());
}
```

However, you can simplify your implementation by just deferring to `Enumerable.Count()`, which I'd expect to be optimized every way you'd like it to be:

```
public static int GetSafeCount<T>(this IEnumerable<T> nullableCollection)
    => nullableCollection == null ? 0 : nullableCollection.Count();
```

Or:

```
public static int GetSafeCount<T>(this IEnumerable<T> nullableCollection)
    => nullableCollection?.Count() ?? 0;
```

(Both assume C# 6...)

At that point, it makes sense to only have two tests: one for a null argument, one for a non-null argument.

Answer (score 0):

He's an example of a `IEnumerable<T>` that is not a `ICollection<T>`:

```
public class MyClass : IEnumerable<int>
{
    public List<int> ints = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var i in ints)
        {
            yield return i;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this as IEnumerator;
    }
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
foreach(var item in new MyClass())
{
    // do something
}
```

But can't do this, since it's not an ICollection

```
var coll = new MyClass() as ICollection<int>; // null!!!
```